# Reading an array into a second array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have an `Object[]` that I need to read the types into a `Class[]<?>`, I am then going to this method

```
public static void invokeMethod(String className, String methodName,
        Class<?>[] paramTypes, Object[] params) {
    try {

        Class<?> commandclass = Class.forName(className);
        Method method = commandclass.getMethod(methodName, paramTypes);
        method.invoke(method, params);

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException
            | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException
            | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Both Arrays cannot have any `null` values otherwise it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Edit: 
Code

```
ArrayList<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
        int i = 1;
        while(true){
            String str = input.substring(input.indexOf(" ", i), input.indexOf(" ", i + 1));
            if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")){
                break;
            }
            params.add(i, str);
            i++;
        }
        ArrayList<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        for(int j = 0; j > params.toArray().length; i++){
            params.toArray()[j].getClass();
        }
```

Later on in code:

```
invokeMethod("com.cjcl.commands.NewCommand", "command", (Class<?>[]) classes.toArray(), params.toArray());
```

Comment: Do you have any example code you've already tried to accomplish this with for some help troubleshooting?

Comment: I have tried with for loops and `ArrayLists` but I cant get the array to have no null values.

Comment: Thats when I tried with ArrayLists

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How do i get no null values

Answer (score 0):

Some modifications to try:

```
    ArrayList<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
    int i = 1;
    while(true){
        String str = input.substring(input.indexOf(" ", i), input.indexOf(" ", i + 1));
        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")){
            break;
        }
        params.add(i, str);
        i++;
    }
    ArrayList<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    // Move the toArray call outside the loop, otherwise it's rebuilding the parameters array each time.

    Object[] paramsArray = params.toArray()
    int paramsArrayLength = paramsArray.length; 

    // EDIT: Changed to j++
    // This for loop needs to be j < paramsArrayLength.  
    for(int j = 0; j < paramsArrayLength; j++){
        classes.add(paramsArray[j].getClass());
    }
```

Most likely, that mixed up comparison operator is your problem.  Since you've got a greater than in there, it's not exectuing. Also, you weren't adding anything to your collection, so toArray was almost certainly trying to make an array out of an empty collection.

Based on the fact that you're initializing `i = 1` and your exception was "index out of range, 1", I also imagine that the code inside the while loop isn't executing.

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0